# OCAML record type

Tags: types, binding, ocaml, record

I am creating an OCAML record type.

```
type matrix =
{m_index:int;n_index:int;matrix:float array array}
;;
```

I have a function that takes two arguments and an array.

```
let create_matrix m n ={m_index=m;n_index=n;matrix=Array.make_matrix~dimx:m_index~dimy:n_index 0.};;
```

However, I get the following error, can anyone explain why?

> Error: Unbound value m_index

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using `m_index` as a right hand value to initialize a field of a record that you are creating.

While initializing a record that contains field `m_index` you can't use this field in an expression assigned to another field of the same object.

Just use directly the `m` argument bound as the argument to `create_matrix`:

```
let create_matrix m n = {
  m_index = m;
  n_index = n;
  matrix = Array.make_matrix m n 0.
};;
```

Comment: o.k. thanks that what i thought too, just wasn't sure about the explanation.